# Prevent ng-repeat until request data is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im trying to prevent ng-repeat runs before the request data is fully loaded into an array, I've done it using a timeout but it only works when the request takes less than I say

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="blocks-container" ng-init="loadProjects()" ng-controller="buildMonitorController">
<div class="row">
   <!-- <div> -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 block animate"
             ng-if="!errorDialogActive && finishedRequest"
             ng-repeat="build in builds.builds.build track by build._id | orderBy:'lastBuildDetails.startDate' : true"
             ng-class="{'running': project.running ,'block-green': build._status ==='SUCCESS','block-red': build._status==='FAILURE'}"
             id="{{build._id}}">
            <div class="title-container"><p>{{build._buildTypeId}}</p></div>
            <div class="update-container col-xs-12">
            <time>{{ build.lastBuildDetails.startDate | date : 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:s'}}</time>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--</div>-->
</div>
<!-- Start error state dialog -->
<div ng-include src="'views/main/error-dialog.html'"></div>
```

And Here is my AngularJS:

```
        $scope.refreshBuilds = function () {
        $scope.errorList.length = 0
        //@TODO remove this part right after the API is working
        //Init
        var suffix = '';
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);


        //simulate mock by random number
        switch (randomnumber) {

            case 1:
                suffix = '-success';
                break;

            case 2:
                suffix = '-less';
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        var url = 'mock/builds'+suffix+'.xml';
        console.log('url: ' + url)
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Basic AAA'
            }
        }).success(function (data, status) {
            //Recive builds from xml and reset scope
            var buildsToFilter = new X2JS().xml_str2json(data);
            $scope.errorDialogActive = false;
            //filter builds which have a no build API detail status
            if (buildsToFilter.builds.build !== undefined) {
                angular.forEach(buildsToFilter.builds.build, function (build, index) {
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: 'mock/build-'+build._id+'.xml',
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: 'Basic AAA'
                        }
                    }).success(function (buildDetailData) {
                        $scope.errorDialogActive = false;
                        //push detail data into build array
                        buildsToFilter.builds.build[index].lastBuildDetails = new X2JS().xml_str2json(buildDetailData).build;
                        console.log(buildsToFilter.builds.build[index]);

                    }).error(function (data, status) {
                        $scope.errorDialogActive = true;
                        //remove build from index if no build detail was found
                        buildsToFilter.builds.build.splice(index, 1);
                        $scope.setError(status, '', '');
                    }).then(function () {
                        //after filtering builds to display, setup builds $scope for FrontEnd
                        $scope.builds = buildsToFilter;
                    });
                });
            } else {

            }

        }).error(function (data, status) {

            //active dialog if error happens & set error
            $scope.errorDialogActive = true;
            $scope.setError(status, 'builds', '');
        }).then(function () {

            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.finishedRequest = true; 
            }, 5000);


            //refresh right after proceed and a little delay
            $timeout(function () {
                console.log('Starting refresh');
                $scope.refreshBuilds();
            }, 21000);


        })
    };
```

Comment: You could manually loop through your data and push it into your array, that way you can keep track of your progress. And use if(i === data.length -1) or something.

Answer (score 2):

You can put condition

`ng-show=builds.builds.build.length > 0`

So when the builds.builds.build have data then only it will be displayed

Comment: Its a good idea, but it begins to render after load the first element and sometimes the query is heavy and the last elements may take some time to load even run the refresh function before the request charge completely

Answer (score 0):

You already have that

```
ng-if="!errorDialogActive && finishedRequest"
```

in place, but you never set `$scope.finishedRequest = false`. What if you simply modify your `refreshBuilds` function like this:

```
$scope.refreshBuilds = function () {
    $scope.finishedRequest = false;
    $scope.errorList.length = 0;
    // etc
```

Does it work then in the way you wanted?

Comment: I know but its working whit the $timeout and I want to change it to true when all the elements are loaded into the array, right now it wait 5seconds to change it, but sometimes it take around a  minute to push all the element into the array and I want to control that.

Comment: What if you don't set `$scope.finishedRequest = true` in your `$timeout`, but only after all the elements are really loaded?